# track session time of user using Global.Asax?

Tags: timer, global

I am building a simple online quiz. When the user submits their details and pressed the ' start quiz button ', I want to be able to track how long it takes for them to do the quiz. I understand you use the global.asax file and add
a session to the application start method.

When the user finishes the quiz they are then taken to a final page which tells them how long it took for them to complete the quiz.

I just want to know do how do I go about creating a timer to track the users time on the quiz. I know I have to minus the timer from the current time to get the total amount of time spent on the website. Do i need to use session states ?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised it there is indeed a session start time already stored somewhere. But if nothing else you could certainly add a session variable on the session start event in global.asax (subject to all the limitations of session state.) The answer probably depends on how finely you want/need to track the time. If it's a one-page quiz then a hidden field might be the simplest approach.

Comment: protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application["StartTime"] = DateTime.Now;

Comment: protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application["StartTime"] = DateTime.Now;

Comment: That's not a per-user variable though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use asp (I've just read where the term "Global.asax" belongs to :), but if you need for some reason to avoid sessions (which are my best friends in the php I use), some ideas are:
1) Take the time of page construction, send it to the page itself, and have the page send it back to whatever processes it, which will then take the time the answers arrive, and you do the magic
2) Too much trouble to have pages sending that extra bit of info back and forth? Save initial time in a file/database

No 1 seems to work specially well in my head for a 1 page quiz.

PS A "timer", in my paranoid understanding of the word, is something that is counting time, which you don't really need if I understood what you want.

Comment: about your explanation, are you able to show a work example, please?